# Spring Boot & Spring boot Admin Can't sent alert email from Docker container

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, spring-boot-actuator, spring-boot-admin

Here in my company we are trying to stablish a micro service based environment, where all the micro services to come will be monitored by an actuator application. We've created two applications, the first micro service and the spring boot admin project, locally all went well and all, then we used docker on this two applications, a container for each one and here start the problems.

Both applications run on port 8080 inside the container, then we assign an external port for its access, this seems to affect the way actuator communicates because now I'm having issues when the client application goes down, the admin is not sending any emails alerting as it did when locally. Here're my configs (changing some parameters):

Client:

.properties:

```
server.port=8080
spring.boot.admin.client.instance.name=Monitoramento Catracas
spring.boot.admin.client.url=http://my-ip:6060
spring.boot.admin.client.instance.service-base-url=http://my-ip:7070
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
  my-service:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: my-file.dockerfile
    image: test/my-image
    container_name: my-container
    ports:
       - 7070:8080
```

Spring Boot Admin Application:

.properties

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.office365.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=email@email
spring.mail.password=12345
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true    

server.port=6060
spring.boot.admin.notify.mail.enabled=true
spring.boot.admin.notify.mail.from=email@email
spring.boot.admin.notify.mail.to=email_2@email
spring.boot.admin.notify.mail.template=classpath:templates/email-template.html
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
  ms-admin:
    build:
      context: ./ms-admin
      dockerfile: ms-admin.dockerfile
    image: cap/ms-admin
    container_name: ms-admin
    ports:
       - 6060:8080
```

And this is what I get when I turn off the client application:

```
2022-12-09 17:06:10.534  WARN 1 --- [or-http-epoll-3] d.c.b.a.s.notify.NotificationTrigger     : Couldn't notify for event InstanceStatusChangedEvent(super=InstanceEvent(instance=2cc8546ac366, version=4, timestamp=2022-12-09T17:06:10.275Z, type=STATUS_CHANGED), statusInfo=StatusInfo(status=OFFLINE, details={exception=org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException, message=finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused: /my-ip:7070; nested exception is io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused: /my-ip:7070}))
ms-monitoramento-hml |
ms-monitoramento-hml | org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.office365.com, 587; timeout -1;
ms-monitoramento-hml |   nested exception is:
ms-monitoramento-hml |  java.net.UnknownHostException: smtp.office365.com. Failed messages: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.office365.com, 587; timeout -1;
ms-monitoramento-hml |   nested exception is:
ms-monitoramento-hml |  java.net.UnknownHostException: smtp.office365.com


ms-monitoramento-hml | Caused by: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.office365.com, 587; timeout -1
ms-monitoramento-hml |  at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2210) ~[jakarta.mail-1.6.7.jar!/:1.6.7]
ms-monitoramento-hml |  at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:722) ~[jakarta.mail-1.6.7.jar!/:1.6.7]
ms-monitoramento-hml |  at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:342) ~[jakarta.mail-1.6.7.jar!/:1.6.7]
ms-monitoramento-hml |  at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.connectTransport(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:518) ~[spring-context-support-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
ms-monitoramento-hml |  at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:437) ~[spring-context-support-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
ms-monitoramento-hml |  ... 124 common frames omitted
```

Hope someone can help me with this one, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error message is very clear, it says

> Mail server connection failed.

> Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.office365.com, 587

So this is an network issue. Maybe there is some kind of firewall blocking the request or the docker containers are not able to reach the internet at all.

Maybe talk to the people who provide the docker host and check the connection rules with them.